# springmvc <mvc:annotation-driven /> and <context:component-scan base-package="" />

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring+SpringMVC demo, I can't understand how to use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`, when I hava `<context:component-scan base-package="com.jiehang.spring.controller"` without `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in spring-mvc.xml. The project can also run, if so, why do we need to write `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in spring-mvc.xml ? Anyone can answer me, please. Thanks

web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

spring-mvc.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jiehang.spring.controller" />
<!-- <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

spring.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thinXXX" />
        <property name="username" value="XXX" />
        <property name="password" value="XXX" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tsmCountsService" class="com.jiehang.spring.service.impl.TsmCountsServiceImpl">
        <property name="tsmCountsDao" ref="tsmCountsDao" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tsmCountsDao" class="com.jiehang.spring.dao.impl.TsmCountsDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class FundController {

    @Autowired
    private TsmCountsService tsmCountsService;

    public TsmCountsService getTsmCountsService() {
        return tsmCountsService;
    }
    public void setTsmCountsService(TsmCountsService tsmCountsService) {
        this.tsmCountsService = tsmCountsService;
    }


    @RequestMapping("/queryFund")
    public ModelAndView queryFundByFundId() {
        List<TsmCounts> funds = tsmCountsService.queryUser();
        System.out.println(funds);
        return null;
    }

}
```

When I input url: http://localhost:8080/TestSpringmvc/queryFund, I can get output result. So, It doesn't matter if you don't write `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

Answer (score 0):

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` provides support for annotation-driven MVC controllers (like @RequestMapping and @Controller) although it is the default behaviour, along with this it adds support for validation via @Valid and message body with @RequestBody/ResponseBody.